# Have one submit button in a form (out of multiple buttons) open a new tab

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form with a button to submit and a button to preview a PDF before submitting. I'd like the preview PDF button to pass the form data to a new page (which will obviously generate the PDF), but the submit button to work on the current page.

I've been looking around but most answers point to using `target="_blank"` in the form tags, though that won't work in my case as that would open every button in a tab. Some others show how to open a window in javascript, but without any form data unless it was passed through the URL.

I only really know PHP and HTML, so I could potentially do it by submitting to the same page, replacing the text in the boxes, and opening a new window in the process, but it'd be a bit overcomplicated just for the sake of a new tab, plus I'd either need to set everything as session variables or pass things through the URL.

Comment: Do you the PDF to be downloaded or only displayed in the browser? Making it download would be more easier.

Comment: I just need it displayed in the browser, it's for the admin to check it over before it's sent in an email, the admin doesn't need to see it again after that. I've got a page set up to generate it btw, I just need it in a new tab :)

Comment: Well one way would be, to store all the form data in a temporary database using ajax, return a unique ID with the ajax result, redirect the user to a different page having that unique ID in the $_GET, show the PDF data and at the end delete it.
A little bit complex, but would serve your purpose.

Comment: Nah, I was needing the form data to generate the pdf :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there didn't seem to be any apparent easy ways of doing such a simple thing, I reworded the question a lot and eventually found something. Turns out there was a super simple way I'd totally missed.

After trying mplugjan's answer, I realised the only easy way would be to have two separate forms for each button (unless I did akshay's suggestion, but that was a last resort), but I'd somehow need to get the values from the main form, which is impossible from a separate form as far as I know. Then I figured I only actually needed the buttons to have different actions, which fortunately did come up with results. It can be done through `formaction` and `formtarget`.

Brief example of how to do it in case anyone else comes across this:

```
<form action = "page.php">
    <input type="submit" value="Accept"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Preview PDF" formaction="pdf.php" formtarget="_blank"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Woah. Never heard of those attributes... Now I see your answer and solution, a script would have been needed in the "old days" to do `onclick="this.form.action='....'; this.form.target='_blank'"`

Comment: Alternatively the data from the other form could have been read from the first form using script as well

Comment: It was when looking up how to read from another form I came across those attributes haha, it did seem a bit fishy there didn't seem to be any way to do something so simple :)

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById("preview").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("previewIFrame").src = "showpdf.php?id=" + document.getElementById("pdfID").value;
    document.getElementById("previewDiv").style.display = "block";
  }
  document.getElementById("close").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("previewDiv").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
#previewDiv {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pdfId; ?>" id="pdfID" />
  <input type="button" value="preview" id="preview" />
</form>
<div id="previewDiv"><span id="close">Close</span>
  <br>
  <iframe src="" id="previewIFrame"></iframe>
</div>
```

Or just

```
<form action="send.php">
  <input name="pdfID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pdfId; ?>"/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<form action="preview.php" target="iframe1">
  <input name="pdfID" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $pdfId; ?>"/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<iframe name="iframe1"</iframe>
```

Comment: Thanks, just trying to get it integrated to see it in action, will this post all the values to the new tab, or does it still need to pass values through the URL?

Comment: The first will GET, the second will GET right now, but POST if you add `method="POST"` to the forms

Comment: The first doesn't seem to work (tried it in jsfiddle as well as on the website and nothing happened), though the second one is a nice idea with loading in a page in the iframe. It doesn't really do the simple thing of posting all the values to a new tab though, using two forms wouldn't really work unless each one could somehow read from another form (and it'd make life so much easier if they could)

Comment: I am then afraid I did not understand what you really want. you are a bit vague about why _blank does not do what you want and whether or not you must post or must get (pass via URL). Please update your question with more information about limitations. Also the close button in my second example could be the submit button to send the form. What does not work in the first example?Errors in the console?

Comment: Sorry about that haha, I tried to explain the best I could but it's not my strong point. By not using _blank as part of the form, I was meaning it would open every button in a new tab which I didn't want (that seemed to make up 90% of the answers to similar questions), I wasn't aware you could set it on individual buttons as I wrote the question :)   I copied into jsfiddle anyway, it's more likely an error on my end, but nothing even happens in the console, the button just doesn't do anything (the 2nd one does though) - https://jsfiddle.net/usoh0vs0/

Comment: Two mistakes - you took the script with the typo (pnclick) before I had fixed it and you chose onload in the fiddle instead of head. This would work: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/dj4m2dzk/ - also see my snippet